# printf in C: Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben) core dumped

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, segmentation-fault, function-call

```
struct node {
    int key;
    char value[32];
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *list = NULL;

struct node *add(struct node *list, int key, char *value){
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->key = key;
    strcpy(n->value, value);
    n->next = list;
    return n;
}

struct node *get(struct node *list, int key){

    struct node *n = list;
    while((n != NULL) && (n->key != key)){
        n = n->next;
    }
    return (n != NULL && n->key == key) ? n : NULL;
}


int main(void) {

    list = add(list, 3000, "Bern");
    list = add(list, 4000, "Basel");
    list = add(list, 8000, "Zurich");

    while (list != NULL) {
         printf("Node %s mit Key %d\n", list->value, list->key);
         list = list->next;
    }

    struct node *n = get(list, 4000);
    printf("Key is: %d \n", n->key);

}
```

I would like to get a pointer to struct node if it can be found in the list. In the code below, I try to print the key of a node (last line in the code), which is in the list, but I get an error. Can someone please help me?

Comment: `struct node *n = get(list, 4000);` at this point `list` has to be a null pointer due to the loop preceding it, so obviously the function also returns a null pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this while loop

```
while (list != NULL) {
     printf("Node %s mit Key %d\n", list->value, list->key);
     list = list->next;
}
```

the pointer `list` is equal to `NULL`. So you may not use it any more to access nodes of the list.

You need to use an intermediate pointer as for example

```
for ( const struct node *current = list; current != NULL; current = current->next ) 
{
    printf("Node %s mit Key %d\n", current->value, current->key);
}
```

Pay attention to that this return statement

```
return (n != NULL && n->key == key) ? n : NULL;
```

can look much simpler as

```
return n;
```

And will be more safer to write

```
struct node *n = get(list, 4000);
if ( n ) printf("Key is: %d \n", n->key);
```